# Retag request for this post on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I would ask one of the SO sysadmins to retag this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609913/what-is-deploying-a-server-closed

The `sql` and `server` ought to be merged into `sql-server`.

I tried flagging the post for moderator attention specifying this - to no avail :-(

Comment: Seems I can't retag a close question. Huh. BTW, Why was it closed on ServerFault? You don't move a question to another site just to have a mod close it as being off topic there. Dumping ground much?

Comment: @TheLQ: Migrated questions are both closed and locked. The latter is why the question cannot be edited in any way except by diamond moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should that question be tagged `[sql-server]`?  As near as I can tell, it's not about Microsoft SQL Server, which is what the `[sql-server]` tag is used for.

Anyway, I removed the `[sql]` tag, since that didn't make any sense either.

Comment: Good catch - thanks - I was just stumped by the "sql" and "server" tags and didn't carefully read the question at all.....